Placing nodes randomly on edges
I am tring to set the pos of an edge node randomly. The following works:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    X/.code={
        \pgfmathparse{rnd}
        \xdef\X{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfkeysalso{pos=\X, label=\X}
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \tikz \draw (0,0) edge node[X] {} (10,0) edge node[X] {} (10,10) edge node[X] {} (0,10);
\end{document}

However, it does not work with an \edef instead of the \xdef. Why? Where is the group closed that \X has been defined in? And is there a more element solution that doesn't require me to do global definitions?

I'm not sure how this is processed exactly but probably \pgfkeysalso gets stored and used later when the actual line and edge is ready to be drawn, which could be several groups outside of X/.code. It would be nice to have some sort of \insertvalue{\X} kind of construct that expands the macro directly (instead of inserting \X itself, that, while expanded, may go out of scope) but as far as I know there is no such thing. However, in LaTeX you shouldn't be too worried about clean scoping, side effects, mixed paradigms etc., the liberal use of these is what makes everything work :)

I wasn't aware of the .evaluted key. For me,
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{X/.style={pos/.evaluated={rnd}}}
\begin{document}
    \tikz \draw (0,0) edge node[X] {} (10,0) edge node[X] {} (10,10) edge node[X] {} (0,10);
\end{document}

did the job. Of course, If I want to use the same random value twice (as in my question), this does not work. But I didn't need that anyway. For that, the .expanded key (e.g., pos/.expanded) might be helpful, but I haven't tried that.
